# Rewrite URL after forum upgrade

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I need to rewrite URLs via .htaccess from the following format:

```
http://www.example.com/showthread.php?threadid=50679
http://www.example.com/showthread.php?s=&postid=837557
```

to

```
http://www.example.com/threads/50679
http://www.example.com/posts/837557
```

The issue is that there already are two similar rules in the htaccess (from previous upgrades) that need to stay intact

```
RewriteRule [^/]+/([\d]+)-.+-([\d]+).html showthread.php?t=$1&page=$2 [NC,L]
RewriteRule [^/]+/([\d]+)-.+.html showthread.php?t=$1 [NC,L]
```

It's starting to get a little confusing with the multiple rules.  Any suggestions?

Edit: Here's the full .htaccess per request in the comments.

```
#   Mod_security can interfere with uploading of content such as attachments. If you
#   cannot attach files, remove the "#" from the lines below.
#<IfModule mod_security.c>
#   SecFilterEngine Off
#   SecFilterScanPOST Off
#</IfModule>

RewriteEngine on

#Redirect contents of previous Xenforo directory to root
RewriteRule ^forums/threads(.*)$ /threads$1 [R=301,NC,L]
RewriteRule ^forums/forums(.*)$ /forums$1 [R=301,NC,L]
RewriteRule ^forums/posts(.*)$ /posts$1 [R=301,NC,L]
RewriteRule ^forums/members(.*)$ /members$1 [R=301,NC,L]

#One more fix from stackoverflow to fix dead /forums and /forums/ links
RewriteRule ^forums/?$ $1 [L,R=301]

#vBSEO to vBulletin URLs
RewriteRule [^/]+/([\d]+)-.+-([\d]+).html showthread.php?t=$1&page=$2 [NC,L]
RewriteRule [^/]+/([\d]+)-.+.html showthread.php?t=$1 [NC,L]

#suggested on stackoverflow to fix pre-2004 URLs
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule     ^/showthread.php?threadid=(.*)$ /threads/$1 [L,R=301]
RewriteRule     ^/showthread.php?s=&postid=(.*)$    /posts/$1 [L,R=301]

# redirect site.com to www.site.com
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [L,R]

ErrorDocument 401 default
ErrorDocument 403 default
ErrorDocument 404 default
ErrorDocument 500 default

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On

    #   If you are having problems with the rewrite rules, remove the "#" from the
    #   line that begins "RewriteBase" below. You will also have to change the path
    #   of the rewrite to reflect the path to your XenForo installation.
    #RewriteBase /xenforo

    #   This line may be needed to enable WebDAV editing with PHP as a CGI.
    #RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
    RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
    RewriteRule ^(data/|js/|styles/|install/|favicon\.ico|crossdomain\.xml|robots\.txt) - [NC,L]
    RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [NC,L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Sure, but the rest of the rules work very well after a lot of trial and error, so I would hate to jeopardize that. :)  Posting the whole thing in the question.

Answer (score 3):

Leading slash is not matched in rewrite rules in .htaccess. Besides you have some missing rules for this.

Your complete .htaccess should be like this:

```
ErrorDocument 401 default
ErrorDocument 403 default
ErrorDocument 404 default
ErrorDocument 500 default

RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

# redirect site.com to www.site.com
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [L,R=302]

#Redirect contents of previous Xenforo directory to root
RewriteRule ^forums/threads(.*)$ /threads$1 [R=302,NC,L]
RewriteRule ^forums/forums(.*)$ /forums$1 [R=302,NC,L]
RewriteRule ^forums/posts(.*)$ /posts$1 [R=302,NC,L]
RewriteRule ^forums/members(.*)$ /members$1 [R=302,NC,L]

#One more fix from stackoverflow to fix dead /forums and /forums/ links
RewriteRule ^forums/?$ $1 [L,R=302]

#vBSEO to vBulletin URLs
RewriteRule /([\d]+)-[^/-]+-([\d]+)\.html$ showthread.php?t=$1&page=$2 [NC,L]
RewriteRule /([\d]+)-[^/.]+\.html$ showthread.php?t=$1 [NC,L]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /showthread\.php\?(?:threadid|t)=([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /threads/%1? [R=302,L]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /showthread\.php\?s=&postid=([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /posts/%1? [R=302,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]

RewriteRule ^threads/([^/]+)/?$ /showthread.php?threadid=$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^posts/([^/]+)/?$ /showthread.php?s=&postid=$1 [L,QSA]

RewriteRule ^(data/|js/|styles/|install/|favicon\.ico|crossdomain\.xml|robots\.txt) - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^ index.php [NC,L]
```

Comment: Hi.  I uploaded this .htaccess in its entirety, and it breaks regular forum topic URLs (not redirects).  Sample URL: http://www.example.com/posts/1615918/

Comment: What is location of above .htaccess? Can you give a sample of full URL that is not working?

Comment: The .htaccess is in public_html root, which is also the forum's root.  I can't post the full URL here but can PM if possible.

Comment: You can replace the domain part by `example.com` and post rest of your URL here.

Comment: I tested this in my local env again and it worked. Isn't `showthread.php` existing in DocumentRoot itself as .htaccss file?

Comment: Yes, showthread.php is in the root directory also.  Threads don't work with this .htaccess enabled, so I had to rever to the earlier version.

Comment: It's starting to look better!  Can we make this kind of URL to work too?  http://www.example.com/forums/showthread.php?t=74469 (it should forward to http://www.example.com/threads/74469)

Comment: Sorry, one additional issue.  Threads from sub-forum called "2010 News" don't redirect properly.  For example: http://www.example.com/forums/2010-news/62241-topic-title.html redirects to http://www.example.com/threads/2010 instead of http://www.example.com/threads/62241.  The redirecting engine doesn't understand that 2010 is a forum name and thinks it's a thread title instead.

Comment: any thread or post URL (http://www.example.com/threads/49282 or http://www.example.com/posts/199492)

Comment: `/threads/49282` loads `/showthread.php?threadid=49282` and `/posts/199492` loads `/showthread.php?s=&postid=199492/`

Comment: /showthread.php?threadid= was the old URL format (from vBulletin) that we migrated away from.  The new one is /threads/

Comment: Right that is understood. I am saying **internally** `/threads/49282` loads `/showthread.php?threadid=49282`

Comment: Internally, it works like this: http://xenforo.com/help/friendly-urls/  , so showthread.php is not a part of XenForo.  However, the engine reads from a MySQL table of archived URLs in order to forward them, and .htaccess rules are supplementing that.

Comment: There is no reference to any `/help/` in your rules. I wonder if we are discussing same thing. You wrote `http://www.example.com/threads/49282` didn't work, what do you mean by that? Did you get 404 or something else?

Comment: The URL above is from the vendor that provided forum software, just to explain their URL structure.  Is there a way to send you the URL directly (not on Stackexchange)?

Comment: You can email me all the details on `anubhava@aol.com` Try to provide as much details as possible,

Answer (score -1):

Pretty sure you can place this in the `.htaccess` or Apache configuration file that controls `www.example.com` and you will be set.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/showthread.php?threadid=/(.*)$ http://www.example.com/threads/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Similarly you can do this for the other example as well.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/showthread.php?s=&postid=/(.*)$ http://www.example.com/posts/$1 [L,R=301]
```

**EDIT** Reread your question & saw the rules you need to retain, so check this out. Order of the rules is key:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule [^/]+/([\d]+)-.+-([\d]+).html showthread.php?t=$1&page=$2 [NC,L]
RewriteRule [^/]+/([\d]+)-.+.html showthread.php?t=$1 [NC,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^/showthread.php?threadid=/(.*)$ http://www.example.com/threads/$1 [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^/showthread.php?s=&postid=/(.*)$ http://www.example.com/posts/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Or what about this?

```
RewriteRule     ^/showthread.php?threadid=(.*)$ /threads/$1 [L,R=301]
RewriteRule     ^/showthread.php?s=&postid=(.*)$    /posts/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Tried that, and it goes to the domain root

Comment: Tried again per your latest edit, still going to the domain root.

Comment: The other rules work fine.  The only one I haven't been able to get to work is the showthread.php?threadid= redirect.  Is that what you're asking?